# Force semaphore to use Java 8

Tags: java, continuous-integration

I have an sbt project which needs Java 8 to run. But the [SemaphoreCI](https://semaphoreci.com/) keeps running it in Java 7 and it fails:

```
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I used this but didn't help:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
```

How can I force Semaphore to use Java 8?

Comment: You're setting *compiler* options - and you're setting those to specify 1.7 rather than 1.8... why would you do that if you know your project needs 1.8 to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Semaphore Java documentation](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/java-continuous-integration.html) tells you how to do this:

> Switching between Java versions is done by adding the following command to your build commands:
>
> ```
> change-java-version <version>
> ```
>
> Valid values for <version> are 1.7 or 7 for OpenJDK 7 and 1.8 or 8 for Oracle JDK 8.

So you need to run `change-java-version 8` or `change-java-version 1.8`. The documentation also gives details of how to do this in a script.